# Are these conditions enough to conclude that $\alpha=\neg\beta$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Let $v',v''$ be different valuation functions on propositional variables and formulas. There are two formulas $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

I know that $v'(\alpha)=1$ and $v''(\beta)=1$. Moreover for any valuation $v$ we have that $v(\alpha\wedge\beta)=0$. Does it follow that $\alpha=\neg\beta$? How to justify that?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: @Shaun certainly we are very closed to $\alpha=\neg\beta$. The only thing which is left to check is if there can exist valuation which makes them both false. I do not see how that option can be excluded.

Comment: Well perhaps it can't ? What if $P$ is a propositional variable not appearing in $\beta$ and $\alpha = \neg \beta \land P$ ?